# Scullyio - How to get Angular Material theme(CSS) also to be rendered in the Static Index.html file after build?

Tags: angular, angular-material, scully, scullyio, angular-scully

I created an `Angular 10` project and integrated angular `Scully` into it using
`ng add @scullyio/init` command.
I am using the `Angular Material` library for toolbars, navbar, buttons, etc.

Now after I build the Angular project using `ng build --prod`, I ran `npx scully` which generated all the static files inside the `dist/static` folder. When I start a HTTP server inside the `dist/static` folder, I am able to see the application rendered with Material theme. But when I don't run any server, and **open just the index.html file in the browser, I am not able to see the Material CSS theme applied, not even the primary color which I had defined for toolbar**.

Please help me to understand what am I missing here so that the static index.html should be rendered with Material CSS even without starting a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the base href in `index.html` from

`<base href="/"> to <base href="./">`

and build again with `ng build --prod` and `npx scully`!